# How to inject several lines of text into a file using PHP?

Tags: php, file-io

Basically I have an array like this:

```
$data = array(
    'aaa' => "moo moo\n",
    'bbb' => "quack quack\n",
    'ccc' => "bark bark\n",
    ...);
```

And then there's a text file like this:

```
field1   value1
field2   value2
field-id   aaa

field1   value1
field-id   ccc
field3   value3

...
```

A blank line in the text file indicates a record separator. I need to inject the array value at the bottom of the record when the array key matches the value of the `field-id` of a record. So the text file for the above example would become:

```
field1   value1
field2   value2
field-id   aaa
moo moo

field1   value1
field-id   ccc
field3   value3
bark bark

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would follow these steps:

- write a reader/writer for your data format
- parse the existing data into a PHP object
- manipulate that PHP object (add the new data)
- serialize the manipulated object into your output format
- overwrite the file

Answer (score 0):

As a quick draft, I'd try something like that:

```
// read in textfile 
$f = file_get_contents('something.txt');

// turn it into an array by separating at empty lines 
$f = preg_split('/^ *$/', $f);

// get search strings as an array
$k = array_keys($data);

// loop over the datasets from textfile 
foreach($f as $ff) {
    // search current dataset with search strings until found 
    foreach($k as $kk){
        if(strpos($ff, $kk) !== false){
            // if searchstring found, append data to dataset
            $ff .= "\n" . $data[$kk];
            break;
        }
    }
    // append dataset to output whether modified or not
    $out .= $ff . "\n" ;
}
// overwrite the textfile with the modified version
file_put_contents('something.txt');
```

This is *not* tested, but should provide a starting point.